# getting date from nullable datetime ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have declared a field in my model as nullable datetime like this

```
public DateTime? CallNextDate {get;set;}
```

in my aspx code behind I am using this linq like this:

```
q = q.AsQueryable()
    .Where(c => c.CallNextDate.Date < DateTime.Now.Date )
    .ToList();
```

but  `c.CallNextDate.Date` is not available. Please suggest how to fix it

Answer (score 20):

Well, if you already know it's non-null, you can use [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydkbatt6.aspx) to get the underlying non-nullable value:

```
q = q.AsQueryable()
     .Where(c => c.CallNextDate.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
     .ToList();
```

Or if you want to filter on that too:

```
q = q.AsQueryable()
     .Where(c => c.CallNextDate.Value != null &&
                 c.CallNextDate.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
     .ToList();
```

I'd *strongly* encourage you to fetch today's date *once* though, and reuse it for the whole query:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
q = q.AsQueryable()
     .Where(c => c.CallNextDate.Value != null &&
                 c.CallNextDate.Value.Date < today)
     .ToList();
```

That will give you more consistency. You should really consider whether you definitely want the *system local date*, by the way.

(Do you definitely need to use `AsQueryable`, by the way? That's relatively rare.)

Comment: What, no love for `GetValueOrDefault()`?

Comment: @JonB: That would work *if* the OP wanted to include all entries with no date. Unfortunately the requirements are very unclear.

Comment: .Value.Date helped me to figure out solution to my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Nullable types have a Value property which represents the underlying type:

```
q = q.AsQueryable()
    .Where(c => c.CallNextDate.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date )
    .ToList();
```

But you will need to check to make sure the type has a value.

```
q = q.AsQueryable()
    .Where(c => c.CallNextDate.HasValue && c.CallNextDate.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date )
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the value you can use:

```
 GetValueOrDefault()
```

**Example:**

item.DOB is a nullable datetime.

```
item.DOB.GetValueOrDefault().Year
```